# Get member of json term

Tags: json, prolog, swi-prolog

I have an API endpoint which returns an array of items.
I want to get every name from the array of items.

The array of items is:

```
[
  {
    id: 30,
    name: "B",
    created_at: "2018-10-15 14:26:23",
    updated_at: "2018-10-15 14:26:23"
  },
  {
    id: 31,
    name: "C",
    created_at: "2018-10-15 14:26:23",
    updated_at: "2018-10-15 14:26:23"
  }
]
```

I currently retrieve it like this:

```
getCarClasses(Object) :- 
HREF = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/classes',
http_get(HREF,Object,[]).`
```

Then I have a function which prints every item, but I don't know how to get the property name.

```
createDynamicCarClassFacts([]).
createDynamicCarClassFacts([H|T]) :- write(H), write('\n'), createDynamicCarClassFacts(T).
```

It currently prints for example:

```
json([id=30,name=B,created_at=2018-10-15 14:26:23,updated_at=2018-10-15 14:26:23])
```

Comment: So, what do you want to obtain as output?

Comment: I want to get the name from from: json([id=30,name=B,created_at=2018-10-15 14:26:23,updated_at=2018-10-15 14:26:23]) for every item

Comment: Look at this page: http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=jsonsupport

Comment: Yes i have seen that, but i don't know how to implement it. I have tried several things.

Comment: In your example, what do you mean by getting the name? Do you want to create a list `L = [id,name,created_at,updated_at]`? Or you want a list `L1 = [30,B,2018-10-15 14:26:23,2018-10-15 14:26:23]`?

Comment: I want to get the value of the name. Like in my json example the value 'B' and 'C'

Comment: Here the same situation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41142552/how-to-get-a-value-from-a-field-in-a-json-string-in-prolog

Comment: Yeah, I have more api calls wich all works where I do it like that, because it returns a json object. But this api call returns a json array. I can't do json(Object) in my api call because it is an array and I get an error. And json(H) also doesn't work in the createDynamicCarClassFacts predicate.

Comment: @damianodamiano I have found the solution. Check my own answer. I added json(H) to the parameter and then I got the normal prolog list.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
I changed the predicate to this:

```
createDynamicCarClassFacts([json(H)|T]) :- member(name=Name,H), write(Name), write('\n'), createDynamicCarClassFacts(T).
```